# markdown-mode seems to ignore variables set in .dir-locals-el

Tags: markdown-mode

I have a folder with some files written in markdown format that I would like to convert in html using `markdown-mode`.

I want a local value for the variable `markdown-css-paths`, in order to have a custom file as style sheet of the resulting html files. So, I create a `.dir-locals.el` file in the same folder of the markdown files and inside it I put this:

```
((markdown-mode
 (markdown-css-paths ("test.css"))))
```

I reload all the buffers, then invoke `C-h v markdown-css-paths [RET]` to make sure the variable is set correctly, which it is:

```
markdown-css-paths is a variable defined in ‘markdown-mode.el’.
Its value is (("test.css"))
Original value was nil
Local in buffer nuovo-corso.md; global value is nil
```

The problem is: when I try to convert the files in html (with the command `C-c C-c m`), no `test.css` style sheet is included.

The same thing happend with at least another variable, `markdown-xhtml-header-content`: it seems as if, during conversion, markdown-mode doesn't rely on the `.dir-locals.el` variable values.

When, instead, I set those variables in `.emacs`, everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using emacs 26.1 and markdown-mode 20180904.1601.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong syntax in your `.dir-locals.el`. You should use association lists, rather than regular lists. i.e., :

```
((markdown-mode . ((markdown-css-paths  . "test.css"))))
```

When I do this, the value of `markdown-css-paths` is `"test.css"`, which is a character string. That's what you need. In your example, the value of `markdown-css-paths` is actually set to `(("test.css"))`, which isn't a string, it's a list containing a list that contains a string.

This is explained in the manual at `(emacs) Directory Variables`. You can find that by:

- `C-h r`, which opening the manual (aka 'r'ead manual)
- `m`, which then prompts you for an item from the menu
- `Directory Variables`, which you can then enter, with the help of tab completion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've read the manual entry you suggested and modified `.dir-locals.el` to use association lists. Sadly, it still doesn't work: markdown-mode outputs html without the correct css file associated. I've also tried to change `"test.css"` to `("test.css")` (`markdown-css-paths` is not a string but a list of string, this was another mistake I made) but without success.

Comment: Hmm. I *think* the problem is that dir-local variables are only in effect for buffers visiting a file in the directory in question. markdown-mode creates the markdown buffers without actually creating a file in the directory first, so the directory local settings don't get applied. I'm not sure how to fix this.